# Tuning MySQL query from explain

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, performance, performance-tuning

I am working on a search query in MySQL. I am getting this from explain:

[image: Explain]

Original [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cf53y1m76)

These are my indexes:

[image: Indexes]

Table definition:

[image: Table]

Original [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d653y1ob4)

Query:

```
SELECT
    `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, 
    `t`.`facebook_id` AS `t0_c1`,
    `t`.`first_name` AS `t0_c2`, 
    `t`.`last_name` AS `t0_c3`,
    `t`.`company_name` AS `t0_c4`, 
    `t`.`member_type` AS `t0_c6`,
    `t`.`gender` AS `t0_c7`, 
    `t`.`birth_date` AS `t0_c15`, 
    `t`.`zip` AS `t0_c22`, 
    `t`.`photo` AS `t0_c25`, 
    `t`.`password` AS `t0_c5`,
    `t`.`email` AS `t0_c8`, 
    `t`.`invite_code` AS `t0_c9`,
    `t`.`can_receive_connection_credits` AS `t0_c10`,
    `t`.`connection_credits` AS `t0_c11`, 
    `t`.`phone` AS `t0_c12`,
    `t`.`fax` AS `t0_c13`, 
    `t`.`website` AS `t0_c14`, 
    `t`.`locale` AS `t0_c16`, 
    `t`.`address` AS `t0_c17`, 
    `t`.`time_at_address` AS `t0_c18`, 
    `t`.`country` AS `t0_c19`, 
    `t`.`state` AS `t0_c20`,
    `t`.`city` AS `t0_c21`, 
    `t`.`zip_longitude` AS `t0_c23`,
    `t`.`zip_latitude` AS `t0_c24`, 
    `t`.`video` AS `t0_c26`, 
    `t`.`passwd` AS `t0_c27`, 
    `t`.`username` AS `t0_c28`, 
    `t`.`about_me` AS `t0_c29`,
    `t`.`how_far_to_travel` AS `t0_c30`, 
    `t`.`education` AS `t0_c31`,
    `t`.`certifications` AS `t0_c32`, 
    `t`.`work_legal` AS `t0_c33`,
    `t`.`has_transportation` AS `t0_c34`, 
    `t`.`ok_with_pets` AS `t0_c35`,
    `t`.`non_smoker` AS `t0_c36`, 
    `t`.`health_insurance` AS `t0_c37`,
    `t`.`languages` AS `t0_c38`, 
    `t`.`communications` AS `t0_c39`,
    `t`.`describe_ideal_job` AS `t0_c40`, 
    `t`.`what_children_like` AS `t0_c41`, 
    `t`.`comfort_children` AS `t0_c42`, 
    `t`.`favorite_books` AS `t0_c43`, 
    `t`.`favorite_music` AS `t0_c44`, 
    `t`.`favorite_movies` AS `t0_c45`, 
    `t`.`hobbies` AS `t0_c46`, 
    `t`.`profile_status` AS `t0_c47`,
    `t`.`profile_visits` AS `t0_c48`, 
    `t`.`background_checked` AS `t0_c49`, 
    `t`.`tozca_verified` AS `t0_c50`, 
    `t`.`verified_date` AS `t0_c51`, 
    `t`.`bchecked_date` AS `t0_c52`, 
    `t`.`verification_paid` AS `t0_c53`, 
    `t`.`background_paid` AS `t0_c54`,
    `t`.`verification_paid_date` AS `t0_c55`, 
    `t`.`background_paid_date` AS `t0_c56`, 
    `t`.`profile_cim_id` AS `t0_c57`, 
    `t`.`payment_cim_id` AS `t0_c58`, 
    `t`.`shipping_cim_id` AS `t0_c59`,
    `t`.`paypal_securetokenid` AS `t0_c60`, 
    `t`.`paypal_productinprocess` AS `t0_c61`, 
    `t`.`verified_transid` AS `t0_c62`,
    `t`.`verified_serialized` AS `t0_c63`, 
    `t`.`background_transid` AS `t0_c64`, 
    `t`.`background_serialized` AS `t0_c65`,
    `t`.`verification_results` AS `t0_c66`, 
    `t`.`background_offenders` AS `t0_c67`, 
    `t`.`date_added` AS `t0_c68`, 
    `t`.`date_modified` AS `t0_c69`, 
    `t`.`ip_added` AS `t0_c70`, 
    `t`.`ip_modified` AS `t0_c71`,
    `t`.`last_login` AS `t0_c72`, 
    `t`.`last_match` AS `t0_c73`,
    `t`.`published` AS `t0_c74`, 
    `t`.`membership_inprocess` AS `t0_c75`,
    `t`.`membership_ends` AS `t0_c76`, 
    `t`.`profile_completed` AS `t0_c77`, 
    `t`.`storage_used` AS `t0_c78`, 
    `t`.`is_claimed` AS `t0_c79`, 
    `t`.`token` AS `t0_c80`, 
    `t`.`slug` AS `t0_c81`, 
    t.id as myid, 
    CASE memberships.trial 
        WHEN 1 THEN 3 
        WHEN 0 THEN 
            CASE mems.is_basic 
                WHEN 1 THEN 2 
                WHEN 0 THEN 1 
            END 
    END AS priority,
    `roles`.`users_id` AS `t1_c0`, 
    `roles`.`roles_id` AS `t1_c1`,
    `services`.`id` AS `t2_c0`, 
    `services`.`users_id` AS `t2_c1`,
    `services`.`services_id` AS `t2_c2`, 
    `services`.`subjects` AS `t2_c3`,
    `services`.`years_experience` AS `t2_c4`, 
    `services`.`availability` AS `t2_c5`, 
    `services`.`online_tutoring` AS `t2_c6`,
    `services`.`hourly_rate` AS `t2_c7`, 
    `services`.`work_sick_children` AS `t2_c8`, 
    `services`.`twin_experience` AS `t2_c9`,
    `services`.`special_kid_experience` AS `t2_c10`,
    `services`.`special_kid_experience_description` AS `t2_c11`,
    `services`.`child_responsability_home` AS `t2_c12`,
    `services`.`working_live_in` AS `t2_c13`, 
    `services`.`specialize_in` AS `t2_c14`,
    `services`.`service_client_office` AS `t2_c15`,
    `services`.`service_client_home` AS `t2_c16`, 
    `services`.`agegroups` AS `t2_c17`,
    `services`.`additionalqualifications` AS `t2_c18`,
    `services`.`why_therapist` AS `t2_c19`, 
    `services`.`what_clients_like` AS `t2_c20`,
    `services`.`whois_your_rolemodel` AS `t2_c21`,
    `services`.`other_services` AS `t2_c22`,
    `services`.`ideal_employer_description` AS `t2_c23`,
    `services`.`what_children_like_aboutyou` AS `t2_c24`,
    `services`.`comfort_separation_anxiety` AS `t2_c25`,
    `services`.`favorite_childrens_book` AS `t2_c26`,
    `services`.`indoor_activities` AS `t2_c27`,
    `services`.`outdoor_activities` AS `t2_c28`,
    `services`.`movies_or_songs` AS `t2_c29`, 
    `services`.`date_added` AS `t2_c30`, 
    `services`.`ip_added` AS `t2_c31`,
    `services`.`date_modified` AS `t2_c32`, 
    `services`.`ip_modified` AS `t2_c33`, 
    `services`.`published` AS `t2_c34`,
    `services`.`licensend_therapist` AS `t2_c35`,
    `services`.`license_state` AS `t2_c36`, 
    `services`.`kind_of_therapist` AS `t2_c37`,
    `services`.`season` AS `t2_c38`, 
    `services`.`type` AS `t2_c39`, 
    `services`.`camper_gender` AS `t2_c40`,
    `services`.`activities_offered` AS `t2_c41`, 
    `services`.`phylosophy` AS `t2_c42`, 
    `services`.`religious_affiliations` AS `t2_c43`,
    `services`.`language_immersion` AS `t2_c44`,
    `services`.`type_of_sport` AS `t2_c45`, 
    `services`.`activity_type` AS `t2_c46`, 
    `services`.`child_gender` AS `t2_c47`,
    `services`.`child_age` AS `t2_c48`, 
    `services`.`name` AS `t2_c49`,
    `services`.`address` AS `t2_c50`, 
    `services`.`phone` AS `t2_c51`,
    `services`.`map` AS `t2_c52`, 
    `services`.`website_link` AS `t2_c53`,
    `services`.`direct_email_contact` AS `t2_c54`,
    `services`.`type_of_vender` AS `t2_c55`, 
    `services`.`robot_indexed` AS `t2_c56`,
    `services`.`company_certifications` AS `t2_c57`,
    `services`.`art_activity` AS `t2_c58`, 
    `services`.`other_arts` AS `t2_c59`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(rate) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN AVG(rate) 
        ELSE 0 
    END as rreviews, 
    CASE 
        WHEN user_reviewed_id IS NOT NULL
        THEN CAST(count(user_reviewed_id) as UNSIGNED) 
        ELSE 0 
    END as nreviews,
    `reviews`.`id` AS `t3_c0`, 
    `memberships`.`id` AS `t4_c0`,
    `memberships`.`users_id` AS `t4_c1`, 
    `memberships`.`membership_id` AS `t4_c2`,
    `memberships`.`membership_name` AS `t4_c3`,
    `memberships`.`trial` AS `t4_c4`, 
    `memberships`.`date_start` AS `t4_c5`, 
    `memberships`.`date_end` AS `t4_c6`,
    `memberships`.`megabytes` AS `t4_c7`, 
    `memberships`.`gallery` AS `t4_c8`, 
    `memberships`.`multiple_locations` AS `t4_c9`,
    `memberships`.`related_business` AS `t4_c10`, 
    `memberships`.`price` AS `t4_c11`, 
    `memberships`.`membership_transid` AS `t4_c12`,
    `memberships`.`membership_serialized` AS `t4_c13`,
    `memberships`.`date_added` AS `t4_c14`, 
    `memberships`.`ip_added` AS `t4_c15`, 
    `memberships`.`date_modified` AS `t4_c16`,
    `memberships`.`ip_modified` AS `t4_c17`, 
    `memberships`.`published` AS `t4_c18`, 
    `mems`.`id` AS `t5_c0`, 
    `mems`.`name` AS `t5_c1`,
    `mems`.`is_basic` AS `t5_c2`, 
    `mems`.`role_id` AS `t5_c3`,
    `mems`.`megabytes` AS `t5_c4`, 
    `mems`.`gallery` AS `t5_c5`,
    `mems`.`multiple_locations` AS `t5_c6`, 
    `mems`.`related_business` AS `t5_c7`, 
    `mems`.`max_file_size` AS `t5_c8`, 
    `mems`.`date_added` AS `t5_c9`, 
    `mems`.`ip_added` AS `t5_c10`, 
    `mems`.`date_modified` AS `t5_c11`, 
    `mems`.`ip_modified` AS `t5_c12`, 
    `mems`.`published` AS `t5_c13` 
FROM `tozca_users` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tozca_users_roles` `roles` 
    ON (`roles`.`users_id`=`t`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tozca_users_services` `services`
    ON (`services`.`users_id`=`t`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tozca_users_reviews` `reviews` 
    ON (`reviews`.`user_reviewed_id`=`t`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tozca_users_memberships` `memberships` 
    ON (`memberships`.`users_id`=`t`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tozca_memberships` `mems` 
    ON (`memberships`.`membership_id`=`mems`.`id`) 
    FORCE INDEX(user_by_zip)
WHERE 
(
    services_id=2 
    AND services.published =1 
    AND 
    (
        roles.roles_id = 2
        OR roles.roles_id = 5
    )
    AND 
    (
        date_end >= "2015-07-29 18:47:03" 
        OR date_end IS NULL
    ) 
    AND t.zip IN
    (
        '91980','91911','91917','91915','91910','91913','91914','91902','91950','919HH',
        '92139','92118','92113','92114','921HH','92102','91935','92101','91977','92106',
        '91978','91945','92107','92105','92104','92103','92115','91941','92116','92110',
        '92108','91942','92019','92109','92120','92020','92119','92123','92111','92021',
        '92124','91901','92117','92037','92071','92122','92040','91916','92121','92126',
        '92131','907XX','92130','92129','92014','92064','92091','92075','92128','92067',
        '92127','92007','92065','92024','920HH','92029','92009','92025','92078','92027',
        '92069','92008','92070','92083','92026','92056','92054','92084','92057','92082',
        '92003','92060','92061','92086','90704','92059','92028','92672','92624','92673',
        '92629','92590','92536','92592','92675','92591','92677','92651','92539','92562',
        '92694','92563','92656','926HH','92625','92661','92653','92662','92657','92691',
        '92595','92692','92663','92660','92679','92688','92630','926XX','92627','92612',
        '92596','92618','92584','92646','92648','92530','92626','92614','92610','92604',
        '92587','92606','92532','92586','92708','92544','92620','90742','92707','92649',
        '92704','92647','90743','90731','92602','92543','91719','90732','92545','92782',
        '92780','92585','92676','92655','927HH','92701','92703','92548','92549','92683',
        '90275','90740','908HH','90803','92705','92843','907HH','92844','92706','90802',
        '90814','92883','90822','90813','92845','90804','90744','92570','90274','92866',
        '92840','92841','92868','92583','92869','90717','90720','90815','92582','90710',
        '90806','90680','92802','90505','92867','92861','90810','928XX','90630','92804',
        '92567','92571','90808','90745','90807','90716','90501','90277','92865','90502',
        '92806','92805','92881','90503','90715','90620','92801','90713','90623','92807',
        '90712','90746','92808','90805','90254','92882','90701','90703','92832','90504',
        '90248','90278','92833','90621','925HH','92831','92879','92887','92870','92886',
        '90706','90260','90266','92551','92508','90220','92518','90247','90221','90261',
        '90249','928HH','90723','90638','902HH','92835','92880','90650','90222','92230',
        '92503','90250','92823','90242','92220','90245','92505','92555','92553','90061',
        '92821','90262','92860','92504','90059','90604','90670','90303','90631','90304',
        '90603','92282','90241','92506','90280','92223','90605','90002','90044','90301',
        '90293','92557','90240','90047','90045','90305','90003','90602','90201','90001',
        '90302','91709','90292','906HH','90606','90255','92507','92320','91748','90056',
        '90043','90270','90660','92501','90291','90230','90040','92509','90058','91745',
        '904HH','91752','90066','90037','90601','90062','91765','90011','90405','90008',
        '90640','90401','91710','91789','91792','90232','90023','90022','90007','90404',
        '90018','90021','91744','90016','92313','90403','92399','90064','92373','90263',
        '91761','90402','900HH','90015','917HH','90014','90013','90025','90063','91766',
        '91746','92337','91754','90006','90019','92318','90033','90272','91733','92354',
        '90265','90017','90035','90071','91755','90067','91762','90005','90212','90012',
        '90057','92324','90010','90024','92374','91791','92316','91768','90211','91770',
        '90020','91743','90049','91790','90036','91763','91732','91803','90048','91731',
        '90004','91764','90026','90031','91767','92408','90032','92359','91723','91706',
        '92339','91724','90210','92335','91776','90038','90029','91801','90069','91722',
        '910HH','90028','90046','90077','923HH','90290','91780','91786','91773','91730',
        '92401','92410','90065','92376','91711','90039','90027','91030','91775','90042',
        '91750','91740','92411','90068','91108','92336','91007','92346','91739','91702',
        '91701','91302','91006','91204','90041','91010','91105','91205','91784','91608',
        '91301','91741','91016','92405','91106','91361','91604','91101','913HH','91737',
        '92404','91107','92377','91602','91403','91203','91423','93041','91436','91206',
        '91364','91356','91024','91207','91607','91202','91103','91505','93033','91601',
        '91316','91104','91506','91201','92305','91320','91367','91401','91502','91411',
        '93035','91377','91606','91501','91208','91362','91001','91307','92407','91303',
        '91405','91335','91504','91406','92382','91605','91360','91306','91011','91020',
        '93030','91304','93012','91402','91352','92358','91759','93010','91214','91325',
        '91343','91324','92315','92341','92325','92386','92317','917XX','910XX','92321',
        '91331','92314','92352','91042','91311','91040','91345','93065','92333','93003',
        '930HH','91326','91344','93004','93063','91340','93066','93021','91342','93001',
        '92397','93060','91321','91381','931HH','93563','93015','92345','93022','93013',
        '93109','91355','93101','93067','93040','91351','93103','93108','93110','93105',
        '93111','93117','91354','92372','92308','92371','93023','91384','91350','92356',
        '93553','92392','93544','93510','930XX','93543','92307','913XX','92394','93552',
        '93550','931XX','93591','93551','93463','93460','92368','92301','93532','93535',
        '93534','93441','93536','92342','93225','93222','93243','92327','93560','92311',
        '92365','92398','92347','93254','93516','93252','93523','93501','93561','93505',
        '93203','93268','93313','93311','93224','93531','93241','92310','93276','93453',
        '93307','932XX','93309','93304','93251','93528','93206','933HH','93301','93518',
        '93305','93312','93306','93554','933XX'
    )
    AND t.published=1
) 
GROUP BY t.id 
ORDER BY priority DESC, rreviews DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

If the `GROUP BY` necessary?  Try removing it; that will eliminate a significant performance hit.  (Or it will give you far more rows than you expect.)

In `t`, this should help:

```
INDEX(published, zip) -- in that order
```

Since both of the 'columns' in `ORDER BY priority DESC, rreviews DESC` are computed, there is no way to avoid finding all the possible rows, then sorting them, before getting to the `LIMIT`.  Hence, as you observed, removing the `ORDER BY` made it run a lot faster.  (It probably grabbed the first 10 rows in the table and did not need to touch the other 15K rows.)

Also, since you are filtering on columns in 4 tables, there is no way to have an INDEX that reaches all the way to the LIMIT.